# When creating a regression model, how to specify a categorical variable?

Tags: r, regression

So I'm trying to create a linear model representation of the following:
[image]

So, `Age.Category` is a categorical variable with the possible values of `Young Adult, Adult, Middle Age Adult, and Senior.`

So I want to do something like this:

```
myModel = lm(Brozek ~ Weight + Age.CategorySenior:Thigh + Age.CategoryMiddle Age Adult:Forearm + Age.CategorySenior:Wrist + Weight:Thigh + Abdomen:Thigh + Abdomen:Wrist, data = bodyfat)
```

but of course that won't work, so how do I make it happen?

Comment: What is your hypothesis and what are the objectives?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to fit your linear model in R? Then all you need to do is to make sure Age.Category is declared as a factor and then included in your lm() model. Something like this:

```
bodyfat$Age.Category <- factor(bodyfat$Age.Category) 

bodyfat$Age.Category <- relevel(bodyfat$Age.Category, 
                                ref="Young Adult")

# Age.Category does NOT interact with Weight
myModel <- lm(Brozek ~ Weight + Age.Category,  data = bodyfat) 

# Age.Category DOES interact with Weight
myModel <- lm(Brozek ~ Weight*Age.Category,  data = bodyfat)
```

Note that R is smart enough to create dummy variables for each of the non-reference categories of Age.Categorical and include them in the model. The reference category is "Young Adult".  You can see this when looking at the summary of your fitted model:

```
summary(myModel)
```

Notice the use of the star symbol for defining an interaction between Age.Category and another variable. Another way to define an interaction term would be with the use of the colon symbol:

```
# Age.Category DOES interact with Weight
myModel <- lm(Brozek ~ Weight + Age.Category + Weight:Age.Category,  
              data = bodyfat)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm using an external library Leaps which only gives me variables by outputting them. So I would have to manually make  the lm() which is why I need to know how to specify each specific value of the category.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that library - maybe someone who is can help you.

Comment: Can you just make dummy variables for each category?

Comment: @OmmKreate Are you using an automatic algorithm for variable selection on dummy encoded factor variables?